# Is there a way to export a Confluence project's documentation to the GitLab Wiki?

Tags: wiki, confluence, gitlab-ce, gitlab-wiki

I would like to take all project documentation at the confluence to GitLab-Wiki.

Is there any way to export from confluence to the GitLab 13ce wiki?

Answer (score 1):

You can export all or parts of you Confluence to PDF (possibly other formats like MS Word?). That may suffice if your Confluence instance is small.

Alternatively Confluence provides a rich [RESTful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29648972/418950) API with which you could [iterate your Spaces and Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50594532/418950), extract all needed details and then format/write them appropriate to GitLab-Wiki (which I don't know anything about). This is non-trivial but I've done something similar using PowerShell and the Confluence APIs.

Comment: Well, that kind off sucks ;)

Comment: @Dennis: It seems improvements may have occurred. See [Export Content to Word, PDF, HTML and XML](https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/export-content-to-word-pdf-html-and-xml-139475.html)